# Is this statement correct : "Certificate of Winner/Champion in English Debating Championship 2022"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, nouns, writing

I'd like to know how to write a statement in a cover letter telling people about a certificate that I got after winning an English debate.

in my application letter where I wrote down like this:

> For your further consideration, I herewith attach the following:
>
> 1. A scanned copy of the Certificate of Champion in Shining High School English Debating Championship 2022,

... and the list goes on.

I would like to know how to put some information about the name of the certificate in my application letter.

Which one is the most appropriate?

1. A scanned copy of the Certificate of Champion in Shining High School English Debating Championship 2022
2. A scanned Certificate of the Winner in Shining High School English Debating Championship 2022

If some of my grammar elements are incorrect, I would be so grateful if you correct them. If you would not mind, probably you might share your explanation why you think a certain structure is rather correct than the other.

Comment: You don't put the scanned copy in your CV at all.  Your CV only refers to the achievement.  You don't put certificates in your CV.

Comment: Is "Shining High School" the name of your school?

Comment: We just name the prize or the honor(s). Like this: Shining High School English Debate Champion 2002 and if you received others, you can use a title like: Honors or Prizes

Comment: I am sorry, everyone. That was not what I meant, I miswrote the description of my question.

What I meant was I will put this statement in my application in which I provide some statements which say:
For your further consideration, I herewith attach the following: 1. A scanned copy of the Certificate of Champion in Shining High School English Debating Championship 2022, and the list goes on..

And now I am having a problem writing down the name of the certificate in a grammatically correct way

Comment: @JamesK: If "Shining" *isn't* the name of the school, it would probably be wise not to mention this award in the first place! If the people who made the award (and thus by implication *named* it) think that's a suitable name, they're probably not qualified to assess the use of English in *any* context, not just school debate societies!

Comment: Hi, guys! I  made up my school's name for my privacy. I am sorry if it causes some problems here.

Comment: There is a real school called "Shining High School"....

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine.  The form "A scanned copy of the certificate" is technically more correct, but there is no doubt what "A scanned certificate" means.

As for the rest, you just use the words that are on the Certficate.  If the certificate says you are the "winner" then use "winner.  If it says "Champion", then use "Champion".   You can use quote marks:

> A scanned copy of my certificate: "Champion of Shining High School English Debate Competition".

Where the words in quotes are copied literally from the certificate.

It might be better not to do this at all.

> I won the Shining High School English debate competition.
>
> etc etc...
>
> I attach scans of my certificates and diplomas,

And let the certificates speak for themselves.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I think that the recruiters here will appreciate that the descriptions are listed in bullet points. Also, if I write down what I did earlier, they instantly get notified from the beginning that the certificate (with its name) is attached plus the order/place where this certificate resides. I'd like to show the recruiters that I spent some time organizing ideas, structures, and documents as neatly as possible and making sure that everything is in its place. Hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Sample: I herewith attach the following: 1. A scanned copy of the Certificate of Champion in Shining High School English Debating Championship 2022, and the list goes on..

First, the thing you won is called an award in English, not a certificate.
Two, therefore, you attach a copy of the award
Three, to attach herewith. Herewith goes after the verb.

I attach herewith:
*A scanned copy of the champion award for the Shining High School English Debating Championship 2022
*[another thing]
*And [another]

The asterisks should be en dashes which I can't seem to get here. Either use the following or herewith, not both.